# Why does this webpack config generate a file called 131.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have this webpack.config.js file to pack my typescript-react project into a single html file.
When i run webpack it generates the index.html file just fine, but also a file called 131.js. Why does webpack this? how can I disable this beaviour? The file is as far as i can tell not used and when deleted, the app works just fine without warnings or errors. I could probably just ignore it, but I want to know.

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin' );
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin' );
const HtmlInlineScriptPlugin = require('html-inline-script-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin = require("html-inline-css-webpack-plugin").default;
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin");

const path = require( 'path' );

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/template.html',
            inject: true,
            minify: {
                html5: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            }
        }),
        new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new HtmlInlineScriptPlugin(),
        new HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin(),
        new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/.(js)$/])

    ],
    output: {
        publicPath: '',
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
        ]
    },
};
```

this is the file:

```
"use strict";
(self["webpackChunkproject_name"] = self["webpackChunkproject_name"] || []).push([[131],{

/***/ 131:
/***/ (function(__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "getCLS": function() { return /* binding */ h; },
/* harmony export */   "getFCP": function() { return /* binding */ d; },
/* harmony export */   "getFID": function() { return /* binding */ L; },
/* harmony export */   "getLCP": function() { return /* binding */ F; },
/* harmony export */   "getTTFB": function() { return /* binding */ P; }
/* harmony export */ });
var e,t,n,i,r=function(e,t){return{name:e,value:void 0===t?-1:t,delta:0,entries:[],id:"v2-".concat(Date.now(),"-").concat(Math.floor(8999999999999*Math.random())+1e12)}},a=function(e,t){try{if(PerformanceObserver.supportedEntryTypes.includes(e)){if("first-input"===e&&!("PerformanceEventTiming"in self))return;var n=new PerformanceObserver((function(e){return e.getEntries().map(t)}));return n.observe({type:e,buffered:!0}),n}}catch(e){}},o=function(e,t){var n=function n(i){"pagehide"!==i.type&&"hidden"!==document.visibilityState||(e(i),t&&(removeEventListener("visibilitychange",n,!0),removeEventListener("pagehide",n,!0)))};addEventListener("visibilitychange",n,!0),addEventListener("pagehide",n,!0)},u=function(e){addEventListener("pageshow",(function(t){t.persisted&&e(t)}),!0)},c=function(e,t,n){var i;return function(r){t.value>=0&&(r||n)&&(t.delta=t.value-(i||0),(t.delta||void 0===i)&&(i=t.value,e(t)))}},f=-1,s=function(){return"hidden"===document.visibilityState?0:1/0},m=function(){o((function(e){var t=e.timeStamp;f=t}),!0)},v=function(){return f<0&&(f=s(),m(),u((function(){setTimeout((function(){f=s(),m()}),0)}))),{get firstHiddenTime(){return f}}},d=function(e,t){var n,i=v(),o=r("FCP"),f=function(e){"first-contentful-paint"===e.name&&(m&&m.disconnect(),e.startTime<i.firstHiddenTime&&(o.value=e.startTime,o.entries.push(e),n(!0)))},s=window.performance&&performance.getEntriesByName&&performance.getEntriesByName("first-contentful-paint")[0],m=s?null:a("paint",f);(s||m)&&(n=c(e,o,t),s&&f(s),u((function(i){o=r("FCP"),n=c(e,o,t),requestAnimationFrame((function(){requestAnimationFrame((function(){o.value=performance.now()-i.timeStamp,n(!0)}))}))})))},p=!1,l=-1,h=function(e,t){p||(d((function(e){l=e.value})),p=!0);var n,i=function(t){l>-1&&e(t)},f=r("CLS",0),s=0,m=[],v=function(e){if(!e.hadRecentInput){var t=m[0],i=m[m.length-1];s&&e.startTime-i.startTime<1e3&&e.startTime-t.startTime<5e3?(s+=e.value,m.push(e)):(s=e.value,m=[e]),s>f.value&&(f.value=s,f.entries=m,n())}},h=a("layout-shift",v);h&&(n=c(i,f,t),o((function(){h.takeRecords().map(v),n(!0)})),u((function(){s=0,l=-1,f=r("CLS",0),n=c(i,f,t)})))},T={passive:!0,capture:!0},y=new Date,g=function(i,r){e||(e=r,t=i,n=new Date,w(removeEventListener),E())},E=function(){if(t>=0&&t<n-y){var r={entryType:"first-input",name:e.type,target:e.target,cancelable:e.cancelable,startTime:e.timeStamp,processingStart:e.timeStamp+t};i.forEach((function(e){e(r)})),i=[]}},S=function(e){if(e.cancelable){var t=(e.timeStamp>1e12?new Date:performance.now())-e.timeStamp;"pointerdown"==e.type?function(e,t){var n=function(){g(e,t),r()},i=function(){r()},r=function(){removeEventListener("pointerup",n,T),removeEventListener("pointercancel",i,T)};addEventListener("pointerup",n,T),addEventListener("pointercancel",i,T)}(t,e):g(t,e)}},w=function(e){["mousedown","keydown","touchstart","pointerdown"].forEach((function(t){return e(t,S,T)}))},L=function(n,f){var s,m=v(),d=r("FID"),p=function(e){e.startTime<m.firstHiddenTime&&(d.value=e.processingStart-e.startTime,d.entries.push(e),s(!0))},l=a("first-input",p);s=c(n,d,f),l&&o((function(){l.takeRecords().map(p),l.disconnect()}),!0),l&&u((function(){var a;d=r("FID"),s=c(n,d,f),i=[],t=-1,e=null,w(addEventListener),a=p,i.push(a),E()}))},b={},F=function(e,t){var n,i=v(),f=r("LCP"),s=function(e){var t=e.startTime;t<i.firstHiddenTime&&(f.value=t,f.entries.push(e),n())},m=a("largest-contentful-paint",s);if(m){n=c(e,f,t);var d=function(){b[f.id]||(m.takeRecords().map(s),m.disconnect(),b[f.id]=!0,n(!0))};["keydown","click"].forEach((function(e){addEventListener(e,d,{once:!0,capture:!0})})),o(d,!0),u((function(i){f=r("LCP"),n=c(e,f,t),requestAnimationFrame((function(){requestAnimationFrame((function(){f.value=performance.now()-i.timeStamp,b[f.id]=!0,n(!0)}))}))}))}},P=function(e){var t,n=r("TTFB");t=function(){try{var t=performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0]||function(){var e=performance.timing,t={entryType:"navigation",startTime:0};for(var n in e)"navigationStart"!==n&&"toJSON"!==n&&(t[n]=Math.max(e[n]-e.navigationStart,0));return t}();if(n.value=n.delta=t.responseStart,n.value<0||n.value>performance.now())return;n.entries=[t],e(n)}catch(e){}},"complete"===document.readyState?setTimeout(t,0):addEventListener("load",(function(){return setTimeout(t,0)}))};


/***/ })

}]);
```

Comment: What is in the file? What size is it?

Comment: You might have a dynamic import somewhere in your code. 131 is the name of the chunk.

Comment: If it's a zero-byte file with a name that matches an output CSS file then it's probably https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/151

Comment: I added the file, its not zero bytes but does also not contain anything of function either.

Answer (score 0):

because in your index.js you call the reportWebVitals() function,
inside this function there is a dynamic import.

Comment: Add quote `` to display code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with the help of supporting information